# Sort Multiple Files Recursively

Tags: bash, sorting, unix, recursion, scripting

I am attempting to sort multiple types of files recursively throughout multiple sub-directories.

Currently I have this, which only sorts through the current directory and only for one specific type of file :

```
for x in *.jpg; do
   d=$(date -r "$x" +%Y-%m-%d)
   mkdir -p "$d"
   mv -- "$x" "$d/"
done
```

I would like the sorting to be able to search through sub-directories, and sort multiple types of files instead of just "*.jpg" files.

Comment: The files this operates on is controlled by the `*.jpg` glob. If you want other files just list them too. `*.jpg *.gif *.txt`, etc. or just list everything in the current directory (careful if there are directories too) `for x in *`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are using `bash` 4, it's as simple as

```
shopt -s globstar
for x in **/*; do
    [[ -d $x ]] && continue  # Skip directories
    d=$(date -r "$x" +%Y-%m-%d)
    mkdir -p "$d"
    mv -- "$x" "$d/"
done
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you. If I wanted to include sub-directories do I just comment out the "[[ -d $x ]] &&" line? When I do that it seems only some sub-directories are moved, not all.

Comment: The problem there is that `**/*` is expanded to the full list before the iteration begins, meaning `x` could be set to a path whose parent was already moved, making `x` a non-existent path.

Comment: Is there any other way to approach it?